# How to disable selected permissions of administrator role from liferay?

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-ide

I just want to hide some options from control panel of administrator role from liferay. Options like "Monitoring, Mobile Device Rules, Portal settings, Plug in installation, Update Manager...etc." . How can i hide each from "portal-ext.properties"? Or Is there any other way?
Please help me..

Comment: How about creating new role and assigning relevant permissions. User then can be allocated with that role. for your requirement you will need to create a regular role and select only required permissions for that role.

Comment: Yes, it is working as you said. Thanks for the reply